# Can you enable SSH on Ubuntu Server automatically after installing?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

The Raspberry Pi OS (formerly known as Raspbian) installer has a feature where you can enable SSH in your install so it opens an SSH server on startup. I'm running some servers on old computers I have and don't want to connect each one of them to a monitor and set the SSH server up. Is there a feature like this on Ubuntu Server? If not, please recommend a server distro that does have this feature. Thanks!

Comment: You've not provided a server product; do you mean Ubuntu Core server or Ubuntu Server?  Depending on product & release; there maybe different *installers* available.

Comment: I honestly don't know the difference lol. I'll go with the safest option Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Ubuntu server has exactly this feature, I thought it was default - I dont remember an install that didnt have ssh enabled. On the newer installers it will even fetch your ssh key from github or launchpad. IIRC its available as "openssh server" in software selections. Have you done an install and found it doesnt have ssh running, or are you just checking?

Comment: Just checking. Thanks!

Comment: The Ubuntu Server installer is designed to be used with a keyboard and monitor anyway, so most users never encounter this question. If you are planning to install Ubuntu Server some obscure way that is completely headless (like using cloud-init), that method should be detailed in your question. The SSH server is enabled by default...but you must create a user account and password/key to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to enable a service on startup is using the following command.

```
sudo systemctl enable --now ssh
```

I'm not sure if there is anything else that prevent ssh for starting automatically as ssh should be enabled by default after installation.